# httputil DumpRequest Host header excluded?

Tags: http, go, proxy

I am writing a http proxy which needs to call DumpRequest. For some reason, the client does not offer "Host" header while the server needs it.   I then do this:

```
if req.Header.Get("host") == "" {
    req.Header.Set("Host", "www.domain.com:80")
}
data, _ := httputil.DumpRequest(req, true)
conn.Write(data)
```

The problem is after I set "host", `data` still does not has it.   I digged into source code of DumpRequest, found this:

```
var reqWriteExcludeHeaderDump = map[string]bool{
    "Host":              true, // not in Header map anyway
    "Transfer-Encoding": true,
    "Trailer":           true,
}
```

Why is `Host` "not in Header map anyway"?

Comment: Host has a dedicated param on the request

Comment: @Chris Townsend  don't understand what this means.  It is the request that my proxy try to forward.  The backend server returns "400 Bad Request missing required header Host"...   That's why I tried to add back the Host: header.

Comment: You don't change the host with `Header.Set`. You access it directly with `req.Host` Like my answer shows

Comment: @ChrisTownsend if you see the source code for Header.Set and Header.Add, the logic is crystal clear.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

I guess you should use `Header.Add()` instead of `Header.Set()`

I didn't try it. So if my answer is wrong, be free to figure it out.

### Reference

From [source code](https://github.com/petar/GoHTTP/blob/1ea15fcd2af0b62584bc0b7920ce944d4e87450c/http/header.go#L21) , It said that.

> It replaces any existing values associated with key

But in you case, you don't have that K existing. So it behaves as we expected.

If you use `Set()` method, it's cool.

Comment: I am sure this answer is wrong. because when I use Set and dump the req.Header, the Host is set.  The only problem is that it is not in the output of DumpRequest()

Answer (score 0):

DumpRequest should not be used to implement a proxy - see [doc](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httputil#DumpRequest):

```
It should only be used by servers to debug client requests. The returned
representation is an approximation only ...
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to change the origin host value of the request while it goes through your proxy, you do not need to change the header of host. You can do the following:

```
if req.Host == "" {
    req.Host = "www.domain.com"
}
data, _ := httputil.DumpRequest(req, true)
conn.Write(data)
```

**Playground**
https://play.golang.org/p/f-qaZRC0RMO

Comment: This is exactly what I did.  Please kindly read the question and test it yourself: after DumpRequest(), data does NOT have the "Host" header in it.

Comment: The playground shows the data is there in the bytes

Comment: This is also not exactly what you did, you are using `req.Header.Set("Host", "www.domain.com:80")` which does not change the host. It doesn't work, whereas this answer uses `req.Host`